# How to incorporate "significance" of a Tukey'sHSD directly into graphs of ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, significance, tukey

I have the following data(dat)

```
V  W  X    Y   Z
1  8  89   3  900
1  8  100  2  800
0  9  333  4  980
0  9  560  1  999
```

I wish to perform TukeysHSD pairwise test to the above data set. From the results of the test, I want to incorporate the significant comparisons in the graph (showing the "*" or "**" sign between the groups that are significant).

This is the code attempted:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
dat1 <- gather(dat) 
ggplot(data = dat1, aes(x = key, y = value)) + stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", colour = "red", size  = 1) 

pairwise.t.test(dat1$value, dat1$key, p.adj = "holm")
```

I do not know if (I can) and how to incorporate the results ("significance") of the test directly into the graph without saving each of the results as an external array and then calling it into ggplot2.

Comment: In the future please remember to include all library statements and use `dput()` (see the R tag description)

Comment: See `help("cld")` in package multcomp as a starting point.

Comment: First of all which of your columns is the key, and which the value

Comment: @DerekCorcoran: After I convert it to long form (gather function), the package automatically converts the data such that all the variables (v,w,x,y,z) are in a single column as key and corresponding number as value